# laravel having: Column not found

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1, having, laravel-pagination

my following code is like this:

```
$places = DivePlace::selectRaw("*,(st_distance_sphere( POINT(".$lon.",".$lat.") ,  point(lon, lat))/1000) as distance")
    ->havingRaw("distance < ".$radius)
    ->orderBy("distance")
    ->paginate(10);
```

without the "havingRaw" everything is good. 
After adding it, the following error came up:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'distance' in
>   'having clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `dive_places`
>   having distance < 300)

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
->where(DB::raw("(ST_Distance_Sphere(POINT(".$lon.",".$lat."), POINT(lon,lat))/1000)"), '<', 200)
```

instead of `->havingRaw("(st_distance_sphere( POINT(?, ?) ,  point(lon, lat))/1000) < ?", [$lon, $lat, $radius])`

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeat distance definition because for pagination Laravel uses only `count(*)` for columns, so it should be:

```
$places = DivePlace::selectRaw("*,(st_distance_sphere( POINT(".$lon.",".$lat.") ,  point(lon, lat))/1000) as distance")
    ->havingRaw("(st_distance_sphere( POINT(".$lon.",".$lat.") ,  point(lon, lat))/1000) < ".$radius)
    ->orderBy("distance")
    ->paginate(10);
```

You could also use bindings for the query, so better would be:

```
$places = DivePlace::selectRaw("*,(st_distance_sphere( POINT(?, ?) ,  point(lon, lat))/1000) as distance",[$lon, $lat])
    ->havingRaw("(st_distance_sphere( POINT(?, ?) ,  point(lon, lat))/1000) < ?", [$lon, $lat, $radius])
    ->orderBy("distance")
    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: hm... it´s a little bit better. 
But now came this error up: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'lon' in 'having clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `dive_places` having (st_distance_sphere( POINT(8.39603, 52.61997) , point( lon, lat ))/1000) < 300)`

Comment: @MathisLogemann Do you have `lon` column in your `dive_places` table? I used the names from your question, maybe it should be `long` ?