# Column not found: execption in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-query-builder

I am working on some maintaince project where all are sql queries but i want to convert it in to laravel. Here is the below query :-

```
$members = Member::select('members.id','members.first_name',
                          'members.surname','members.username','members.password',
                          'members.email','user_access.active',
                          DB::raw('SUM( IF (user_access.active = "y", 1, 0) ) as acount'))
        ->join('user_access','user_access.member_id','=','members.id')
        ->where('special_access','=','n')
        ->groupby('user_access.member_id')
        ->having('acount','>','0')
        ->orderby('members.id','desc')
        ->orderby('members.username','ASC')
        ->orderby('user_access.note','DESC')
        ->paginate(30);
```

Its giving me error when i execute the query. below the error in having clause

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'acount' in 'having clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `members` inner join `user_access` on `user_access`.`member_id` = `members`.`id` where `special_access` = n group by `user_access`.`member_id` having `acount` > 0)
```

Comment: its acount means activecount that means active column in user_access table

Comment: its not that my account.. please check my query carefully

Comment: You should show your table column details too, no one will understand the table structure and can't help you.

Comment: Try havingRaw(DB::raw('SUM( IF (user_access.active = "y", 1, 0) ) as acount')>0) instead of your having

Comment: Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression could not be converted to int

Comment: The paginator will attempt to get the count of the query and will remove all selects from it when doing so leading to this error. Unfortunately, you may need to manually paginate your result.

Comment: yes when i changed to get instead of paginate its start working is there any way to run with pagination?

Comment: Check [the pagination docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination#paginating-eloquent-results). You may be able to get it to work using `simplePagination` but if not then you'll have to manually paginate. Problem is getting the total number of results when using group by and having is not simple.

Comment: You can also try @MD.JubairMizan suggestion but with `havingRaw('SUM...` (without the DB::raw in there since that's double raw)

Comment: i already tried but not working

Comment: @apokryfos simple pagination is working but how to add numbering in simple pagination

Comment: `simplePagination` does not get the total number of pages which is why it's working. You can't get the pages in there with simple pagination.

Comment: @kunal Change your config/databse.php mysql strict= false . If you wish to ignore unwanted error

Comment: @MD.JubairMizan Its already false

Comment: Any one can tell me is there anyway to do or someone having knowledge of eloquent queries can update the query...

Comment: Try where instead of having https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982661/laravel-having-column-not-found

Comment: @MD.JubairMizan same error

Comment: @kunal For debug purpose can you remove the having() column and check you get the data

Answer (score 1):

I guess something like this will help you.

```
$userAccess = DB::table('user_access')
    ->where('special_access','=','n')
    ->where('active','y')
    ->groupby('member_id');

Member::select([
    'members.id', 
    'members.first_name', 
    'members.surname', 
    'members.username', 
    'members.password', 
    'members.email', 
    'user_access.active'
])->joinSub($userAccess, 'user_access', function($join){
    $join->on('user_access.member_id', '=', 'members.id');
})->orderby('members.id','desc')
->orderby('members.username','ASC')
->orderBy('user_access.note','asc')
->paginate(30);
```

OR

```
$members = Member::select([
    'members.id', 
    'members.first_name', 
    'members.surname', 
    'members.username', 
    'members.password', 
    'members.email', 
    'user_access.active'
])->join('user_access', function($join){
    $join->on('user_access.member_id', '=', 'members.id')->on('user_access.active', '=', DB::raw('"y"'));
})
    ->where('special_access','=','n')
    ->groupby('user_access.member_id')
    ->orderby('members.id','desc')
    ->orderby('members.username','ASC')
    ->orderby('user_access.note','DESC')
    ->paginate(30);
```

> **As [apokryfos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487813/apokryfos) said in the comments:**
>
> The paginator will attempt to get the count of the query and will remove all selects from it when doing so leading to this error.

If you just need records with `user_access.active = "y"` then you do not need to select them in the first place and then try to filter them out by `HAVING`

Comment: BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::joinSub()

Comment: joinSub is available on laravel 5.7, could you try the second code i just added to the post?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'y' in 'on clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `members` inner join `user_access` on `user_access`.`member_id` = `members`.`id` and `user_access`.`active` = `y` where `special_access` = n group by `user_access`.`member_id`)

Comment: sorry, this'll work: `->on('user_access.active', '=', DB::raw('"y"'))`

Comment: your this answer is working fine... can you help me with this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54735320/sqlstate42s22-column-not-found-in-laravel-affte-using-having-clause

Comment: now i am fetching results wih having acount is 0 .. Please help me :(