# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: in laravel affte using having clause?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am working on laravel project but firstly it was created in core php. I am stuck in one query that is working fine in sql query but when i convert in to laravel its showing error... Sql query is below:-

```
SELECT *,MAX(UNIX_TIMESTAMP( if(last_recur_date IS NULL, 
subscription_date,last_recur_date) )) as max, SUM( IF (active = 'y', 1, 0) ) AS 
acount, m.id AS member_id FROM members m INNER JOIN user_access_old ua ON m.id 
= ua.member_id GROUP BY m.id having acount=0 ORDER BY max DESC, m.id DESC, 
username ASC, ua.note DESC
```

But when i try using below laravel query its showing error:-

```
$members = Member::query();
$members = $members->join('user_access','user_access.member_id', '=', 'members.id')->select('members.id','members.first_name',
                          'members.surname','members.fullname','members.member_date','members.username','members.password',
                          'members.email','user_access.active','user_access.special_access','user_access.note',
                          DB::raw('SUM( IF (active = "y", 1, 0) ) AS acount'))
                    ->groupby('members.id')
                    ->having('acount',0)
                    ->orderby('max','desc')
                    ->orderby('members.id','desc')
                    ->orderby('members.username','ASC')
                    ->orderby('user_access.note','DESC')
                    ->paginate(60);  // when i replaced to get its working fine but i want to paginate the data
```

Its showing below eroor :-
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'acount' in 'having clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `members` inner join `user_access` on `user_access`.`member_id` = `members`.`id` group by `members`.`id` having `having acount` = 0)

Comment: Why do you use `having acount` as an argument for the `having` method? Have you tried using `acount` only?

Comment: when i use where('active','n') its giving wrong results but having clause is sql query or changing pagiante to get its giving correct results

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40194120/how-to-use-having-with-paginate-on-relationships-column-in-laravel-5) post of using `paginate` with `having` clause.

Comment: Also you missed adding select for `max` alias